# Excel 3-Color Scale Conditional Formatting with Formula

Tags: excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I am trying to have a cell color to one of three colors if a formula is returned as 'True' using the Conditional Formatting 3-Color Scale. is this possible?

Red = `AND($C$22>0,$C$20>$C$25)`

Yellow = `AND($C$22>0,$C$20<=$C$25)`

Green = `C22<0`

Image starts at cell 19, listed at right

[image: Image starts at cell 19, listed at right]

Comment: you need to set up three seperate formatting rule using the formulas you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it's possible through **Use a formula condition....**

**Way to apply the formula conditional format :**

```
Home => Conditional Formatting => Manage Rules => New Rule => Use a formula to determine...
```

Apply your formulas to get exact result as you liked.

here is the sample snap that i have tried.

[image]

[image]